# Python xml parsing using xml.etree.ElementTree not working

Tags: python, xml

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<nowdisplaying deviceID="000C8" source="AIN">
<ContentItem source="AIN" istable="true"/>
<Status>L_STATE</Status>
</nowdisplaying>
```

I have this xml page above that i need to parse to get the source info that is in the nowdisplaying tag.  Any idea how I can do that? I am having hard time doing that using xml.etree.ElementTree. I can only get the status information.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('status.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
status = root[0].text
```

Comment: Post the code you're using to get the `Status` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the above XML is literally your whole data, displaying the source requires just a couple lines of code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''
<nowdisplaying deviceID="000C8" source="AIN">
<ContentItem source="AIN" istable="true"/>
<Status>L_STATE</Status>
</nowdisplaying>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(data)
print("source:", root.get("source"))
```